# problem; primitive root

Tags: elementary-number-theory

a) There are as many primitive roots of $2p^n$ as $p^n$.

b) Any primitive root r of $p^n$ is also a primitive root of p.

c) A primitive root of $p^2$ is also a primitive root of $p^n$ for n >= 2.

Im so sorry . My professor teachs so quickly then I cant organize my thoughts...
so It is better to see your solution and organize my ones.

finally do you know that there is a Burton's Elementary Number Theory solution??
I cant find that in google...

thnks!

Comment: For (a) see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994510/let-p-be-an-odd-prime-suppose-that-a-is-an-odd-integer-and-also-a-is-a-pr.

Comment: For (b) see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170648/prove-that-any-primitive-root-r-of-pn-is-also-a-primitive-root-of-p

Comment: What exactly is the question here???

Comment: please solve... and doyou know there are solutions? :(

Comment: Please solve what?????

Comment: a...b...c... I think it is rude... sorry but maybe i need only c

Comment: For c), there's http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31679/if-g-is-a-primitive-root-of-p2-where-p-is-an-odd-prime-why-is-g-a-prim

Comment: gosh how can do that...tell me

Comment: a is not same thing :(

Comment: I don't know what "how can do that" means, or what it refers to, or to whom it is addressed.